# Узнать когда отработала `CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX`

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно узнать когда закончила работу процедура `CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX`
Есть процедура

```
PROCEDURE SyncIndex
IS
    BEGIN
        CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX('OBJ_IDX');
    END;
```

Нужно узнать когда она окончить работу после запуска. То есть вопрос в том как мониторить выполнение данной процедуры?
Пробовал так:

```
select sess.sid as "Session ID", sql.sql_text as "Index Operation",
       longops.totalwork, longops.sofar, 
       longops.elapsed_seconds/60 as "Runtime Mins",
       longops.time_remaining/60 as "ETA Mins"
from   v$session sess, 
       v$sql sql, 
       v$session_longops longops
where  sess.sid=longops.sid
and    sess.sql_address = sql.address
and    sess.sql_address = longops.sql_address
and    sess.status  = 'ACTIVE'
and    upper(sql.sql_text) like '%INDEX%'
order  by 3, 4;
```

но это мне не помогло.

Есть какие - нибудь варианты решения моей проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модернизируйте вашу процедуру так, чтобы она сохраняла логи.
Примерно как то так:

```
PROCEDURE SyncIndex IS
BEGIN        
    insert into <ваша таблица с логами о начале задания>;
    CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX('OBJ_IDX');
    insert into <ваша таблица с логами об окончании задания>;
END;
```

Тогда вы всегда сможете понять, отработала ли ваша процедура, и знать сколько она уже проработала.

Comment: а нет ли других способов узнать эту информацию в оракле? каких то системных таблиц, куда пишется инфа про индексы и их работу?

Comment: `select INDEX_NAME, last_analyzed from all_indexes i where i.INDEX_NAME=<ваш индекс>` возможно поможет. Не уверен на 100%, что можно положиться на эту дату. ИМХО, собственное логгирование лучше.